# Checking the Range of a Number in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, range

I have a simple PHP script that is checking the range of a number. For some reason, once the number I am checking equals `100%` the code does not work. Here is my code:

```
$percent_completed = '100%';                            

if ($percent_completed <= '20%') {
    $color = 'danger';
} elseif ($percent_completed >= '21%' && $percent_completed < '40%') {
    $color = 'warning';
} elseif ($percent_completed >= '40%' && $percent_completed < '60%') {
    $color = 'info';
} elseif ($percent_completed >= '60%' && $percent_completed < '80%') {
    $color = 'primary';
} elseif ($percent_completed >= '80%' && $percent_completed < '100%') {
    $color = 'default';
} else {
    $color = 'success';
}

echo $color;
```

All of the conditional checks above work just fine until `$percent_completed` is equal to `100%`. For some reason it is set to `100%` the `$color` that is printed out is `danger`. I am sure it is a simple fix but everything I have tried does not work.

Comment: You should use real numbers and not strings for this. Also, the first condition of all the double conditions is redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the `%` from your `$percent_completed` variable. It makes it as string which will give you different results than when comparing as a integer (for numbers).

```
$percent_completed = 100;                            

if ($percent_completed <= 20) {
    $color = 'danger';
} elseif ($percent_completed < 40) {
    $color = 'warning';
} elseif ($percent_completed < 60) {
    $color = 'info';
} elseif ($percent_completed < 80) {
    $color = 'primary';
} elseif ($percent_completed < 100) {
    $color = 'default';
} else {
    $color = 'success';
}

echo $color;
```

Comment: No need to even use quotes. It's an integer

Comment: Also, no need for the `>=` conditions as they are already met.

Comment: @JohnConde you are missing the opening `(` on line `} elseif $percent_completed < 60) {`

Answer (score 4):

You're doing calculations on a string.

That means that '2%' is actually higher than '100%' (for example).

Remove the percentage symbol and use it when required during output.

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out another approach, I'm posting an alternative solution. Sometimes it's more readable to use a simple algebric formula instead of plenty of if-else conditions.

```
//Assign current percent value to a variable
$percent_completed = 100;
//Assign an array of all notifications
$array_notifications = array("danger", "warning", "info", "primary", "default", "success");
//Calculate index of current notification
$current_index = floor($percent_completed / 20);
//Print or do something else with detected notification type
echo $array_notifications[$current_index];
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution - just be aware that it relies on the result of `$current_index` being both an integer, and in the range of `$array_notifications`. In this specific case, it will always be an integer, so that's ok. Be careful with the 0-based index of the array though -- you'd need to do something like `$array_notifications[$current_index - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this considerably.

- Remove the quotes (numbers are integers)
- Remove the % signs from your percentages for calculation
- php processes the first successful `if` statement correctly and exits the condition. Stack from top to bottom, and you use 1/2 the code. (Or you could write it bottom to top and use `>` instead).

---

```
$p = 100;                            
if ($p == 100)
    $color = "success";
elseif ($p >= 80)
    $color = "default";
elseif ($p >= 60)
    $color = "primary";
elseif ($p >= 40)
    $color = "info";
elseif ($p > 20)
    $color = "warning";
elseif ($p <= 20)
    $color = "danger";
echo $color;
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing percentage strings *could* work if you're using a natural-order compare function.

Natural order compare functions separate strings and numbers and will treat the numbers as numbers rather than string.

So instead of:

```
[ "1", "10", "2" ]
```

You will get:

```
[ "1", "2", "10" ]
```

Some languages have this function built in (like PHP: [strnatcmp](http://php.net/strnatcmp)) but JavaScript sadly does not. Writing your own implementation is not very hard, but it's not very easy either.

In this case I would definitely recommend simplifying (like John's solution).